# how query object from a value in an array that's a subproperty

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Giving an array that's placed in a subproperty of a mongoose schema.
How to find an element with as a filter, a value that's in this array.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sampleSchema = new Schema({   
    dates: [{
    date: Date,
    duration: Number   }] });

sampleSchema.find( { dates : { $elemMatch: {  date : { $gte: 'DATE_VALUE' } } } )
```

i think this is what you are looking for.